# How to send email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, actionmailer

The following is my controller file:

```
class BiodataController < ApplicationController
  def store
    @user=params[:username]
    @age=params[:age]
    @gender=params[:gender]
    @mstatus=params[:mstatus]
    @language=params[:language]
    @email=params[:email]
    @mobile=params[:mobile]

    if params[:username].present? && params[:age].present? && params[:gender].present? && params[:mstatus].present? && params[:language].present? && params[:email].present? && params[:mobile].present?
        Biodatum.create(name: @user, age: @age, gender: @gender, mstatus: @mstatus, language: @language, email: @email, mobile: @mobile)
    Infomail.sendmail(@email)
    render 'store'
    else
        render 'Error'
    end
  end
end
```

My requirement is to send email to the address stored in @email. So I created the mailer as 'Infomail'. The following is my mailer file.

```
class Infomail < ApplicationMailer
    default from: 'abc@xyz.co.in'

    def sendmail(user)
        @user = user
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'sample mail')
    end
end
```

And I also have html file under 'app/views/infomail/sendmail.html.erb'. But it doesn't work. Can any one explain me what is the bug in
my code.

Comment: `Infomail.sendmail(@email)` here you create the email, but never do anything with it. Try this: `Infomail.sendmail(@email).deliver_now`. Also, check you email configurations on the environments configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend that you take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html for starters.

For sending mails, you'll have to use the `deliver_now` (Immediate) or `deliver_later` (Queue for worker) methods, like so:

```
InfoMailer.sendmail(@user).deliver_now
```

Note that I renamed it to `InfoMailer`, because that's the standard naming, of mailers.

Comment: It shows error as "undefined method `email' for "abc@xyz.co.in":String"

Comment: That's because you're passing a string as `@user` and not passing `@bio`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `@email` which is a `String` in params while you are expecting `Object` on which you can call `.email`

```
@bio = Biodatum.create(name: @user, age: @age, gender: @gender, mstatus: @mstatus, language: @language, email: @email, mobile: @mobile)
Infomail.sendmail(@bio)
```

This will pass `Biodatum` instance on which you can call `.email`

Also to avoid confusion you can change your mailer method

```
def sendmail(bio)
  @bio = bio
  mail(to: @bio.email, subject: 'sample mail')
end
```

If you are making these changes, you will also need to change them in `sendmail.html`

**EDIT**

Make sure you have configured the settings in `/config/environments/development.rb` and `/config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => ENV['gmail_username'],
  :password             => ENV['gmail_password'],
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: How rails knows what is the "to" address. Because @bio contains many details as name, age, gender etc...

Comment: you are calling `.email` on `@bio` in your mailer ---> `@bio.email`

Comment: It successfully render the "store" page. But It doesn't send any mail

Comment: Have you configured `action_mailer.smtp` settings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test you mailer into development environment just open your development.rb file and write below code inside for smtp configuration.

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options  = { host: 'url of your application' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'address of your mailer',
    port:                 465,
    domain:               ENV['YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME'],
    user_name:            ENV['YOUR_USER_NAME'],
    password:             ENV['YOUR_PASSWORD'],
    authentication:       :plain,
    ssl:                  true,
    tls:                  true,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

please change above configuration as per your mailer smtp settings.
Now create tamp let of your mail as per you requirements. file path as per below:
app -> view -> common_mailer inside of this please make sendmail.html.erb file.

Comment: Please Inherit your Infomail directly with ActionMailer::Base if you does not need to done by 2nd step. as per below:
class Infomail < ActionMailer::Base
end